# How to combine static Icon with animated Icon

Tags: java, swing, icons

I have two Icons which one of them has a `.gif` as an Icon, and the other a `.png`. So I would like to combine this icons to put the animated one above the other.

This code works with `static` Icons, but at time to put an `animated` one, it doesn´t print the animated.

```
public class Combine implements Icon{

    private final Icon back;
    private final Icon front;

    public Combine(Icon pBack, Icon pFront) {
        this.back= pBack;
        this.front= pFront;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return Math.max(front.getIconHeight(), back.getIconHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return Math.max(front.getIconWidth(), back.getIconWidth());
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component arg0, Graphics arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        back.paintIcon(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
        front.paintIcon(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }

}
```

I am loading the icons using this:

```
Icon back = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MyClass.class.getResource(source)));
Icon front = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MyClass.class.getResource(source)));
```

**EDIT:**

I want to use the icon for a JButton icon.

Answer (score 1):

> one of them has a .gif as an Icon,

I think you need to use a JLabel to have the animation. That is the JLabel is responsible for repainting the Icon as it animates.

Try just displaying the two Icons in two JLabels:

```
JLabel front = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
JLabel back = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
back.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
back.add(front, new GridBagConstraints());
```

The front icon should be centered on the back icon.

You may also want to check out [Compound Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/) which is a more flexible version of your class that allows you to combine 2 or more Icons into one.

Comment: I want to use that icon for the icon of a JButton

Comment: @jajasuperman, The Icon doesn't do the animation, so you need the JLabel to do the animation for you. I found this posting:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854629/why-is-an-animated-gif-icon-not-showing-in-jtable-column, which suggests how you might be able to duplicate this logic by doing your own animation of the gif. Or maybe a simpler approach would be to create your own [Animated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/animated-icon/). Using this approach you provide a series of images and the Icon will display each image based on a Timer.

Comment: it does the animation if I put `button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MyClass.class.getResource("/my.gif"))))`. But when combining it with the static one, it only shows the static. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the animated ImageIcon to notify the JButton whenever a new frame becomes available:

```
front.setImageObserver(button);
```

See [ImageIcon.setImageObserver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#setImageObserver-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-) for details.

By the way, ImageIcon has a constructor that takes a URL:

```
ImageIcon back = new ImageIcon(MyClass.class.getResource(backSource));
ImageIcon front = new ImageIcon(MyClass.class.getResource(frontSource));
```